how to keep window color changed in pygame
Im trying to make it so when my picture bounces, the window changes to a random color, but when it changes, it only changes for a split second when it collides then the window changes back to white
when i remove screen.fill, it keeps the random color for every bounce, but then it leaves a trail of images
import pygame
import random

height = 500
width = 500

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('epic trampoline')
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink']

running = True
win_color = 'white'
trampoline_color = 'black'
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

image = pygame.image.load('epicface.png').convert_alpha()
epic_image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (50, 50))  # changing size

epic_rect = epic_image.get_rect(center=(250, 0))  

gravity = 0
acceleration = 1

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    clock.tick(30)
    gravity += 0.6 
    window.fill('white')
    epic_rect.bottom += gravity

    # rect = pygame.draw.rect(window, 'white', epic_rect)

    trampoline = pygame.draw.rect(window, trampoline_color, pygame.Rect(0, 440, 500, 10))
    collide = pygame.Rect.colliderect(trampoline, epic_rect)

    if collide:
        epic_rect.bottom = trampoline.top
        win_color = window.fill(random.choice(colors))
        gravity = -18 

    window.blit(epic_image, epic_rect.topleft)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.display.flip()


Create a variable for the colur and use it to fill the window. Change the variable when there is a collision
fill_color = 'white'
trampoline = pygame.Rect(0, 440, 500, 10)

while running:  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    clock.tick(30)
    
    gravity += 0.6 
    epic_rect.bottom += gravity
    collide = pygame.Rect.colliderect(trampoline, epic_rect)
    if collide:
        epic_rect.bottom = trampoline.top
        fill_color = random.choice(colors)
        gravity = -18 

    window.fill(fill_color)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, trampoline_color, trampoline)
    window.blit(epic_image, epic_rect.topleft)
    pygame.display.flip()


